# setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true): Is widget.hide() == widget.close()?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, show-hide, event-loop

When running the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication application{argc, argv};
  application.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);

  QLabel a("a");
  a.setMinimumWidth(400);
  a.show();

  QLabel b("b");
  b.setMinimumWidth(400);
  b.show();

  QTimer::singleShot(10000, [&]() { b.hide(); });

  return application.exec();
}
```

The following happens:

- Qt opens a window "a" and a window "b"
- Afer 10 seconds, Qt hides window "b" after 10 seconds.

When I now close window "a" manually, the Qt eventloop quits, **even though there is still a non-closed window "b" (which is hidden).**

Why? Shouldn't Qt wait until "b" is closed, not only hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
From the docs on the [lastWindowClosed](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#lastWindowClosed) event:

> This signal is emitted from QApplication::exec() when the last visible primary window (i.e. window with no parent) with the Qt::WA_QuitOnClose attribute set is closed.